# pgAdmin III (Windows) - Sharing DB Connection Definitions

Tags: windows, postgresql, registry, pgadmin

I'm trying to copy a pgAdmin III server list from a source machine (which has my established list) to a target machine (with pgAdmin newly installed).  Both run Windows 7 Pro, the pgAdmin version is 1.18.1 .

Based on answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464396/pgadmin-sharing-db-connection-definitions) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9837222c0909291019v4b921d3en159791bde103368c@mail.gmail.com), I have exported the Registry definition at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III\Servers` from the source machine and imported it into the target machine, apparently successfully: the entries for all 9 servers show up, and the value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III\Servers\Count` is 9.

But when I start pgAdmin, no servers show up, even though its status line shows the message "Retrieving details on servers... Done."  And when I look back at the Registry, the value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III\Servers\Count` is back to 0 (tho the 9 server definitions are still there).

So my question is: How to get the new install of pgAdmin to find the imported servers list?

Comment: You might have more success with this question at http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgadmin-support/

Comment: you may find the answer to your question by following this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464396/pgadmin-sharing-db-connection-definitions.