# How to import server list between pgadmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin

How to import/export server lists between pgadmin 4.2  between  computer (in Windows)?

I found some links for pgadmin 3 regarding registry. Would that be same for 4 too.

[pgAdmin - Sharing DB Connection Definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464396/pgadmin-sharing-db-connection-definitions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45823367/89346, configuration data seems to be available in `C:\Users\{Your_User}\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin`. You may try to copy the `pgAdmin` directory across different machines

Comment: Copy paste-able path:`%appdata%\pgadmin`

Answer (score 10):

Documentation exists for this, here: [Exporting and importing Servers](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/import_export_servers.html)

When you install pgAdmin4 on Windows, e.g. **C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4** for version pgAdmin4 v4.2 in my case, there is a subfolder named **venv** which hosts another **Scripts** subfolder in which is stored Python Virtual Environment mentioned in documentation.

This is the python.exe that we can use to dump the servers list.
Open a command prompt (Win + R, cmd), and browse to this **Scripts** subdirectory

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Scripts"
```

The command I used to create the dump is:

```
python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\web\setup.py" --dump-servers D:\dump\pgAdmin4_servers_list.json
```

If successful, message stating number of servers descriptions dumped will be displayed.
In my case:

```
Configuration for 43 servers dumped to D:\dump\pgAdmin4_servers_list.json.
```

Then, copy the JSON file to the new computer and, using a command prompt, browse to the same subdirectory as before:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv\Scripts"
```

Before import, make sure pgAdmin4 server is shutdown.
Now you can import the JSON file content (E: is my flash drive letter):

```
python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\web\setup.py" --load-servers E:\dump\pgAdmin4_servers_list.json
```

If successful, it should display the number of server groups and servers added.
In my case:

```
Added 5 Server Group(s) and 43 Server(s).
```

Restart pgAdmin4 and you should see your server list as it was on the source.

Comment: had to `set "PYTHONHOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v4\venv"` or was getting `failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding`

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the below steps to Import and Export Servers list between pgAdmin 4 by using the pgAdmin application.

**Export Server List**

- Open pgAdmin and click on **Tools->Import/Export Servers**
- Import/Export UI will be poped-up
- Select **Export** and locate your exported JSON file [image]
- Select expected server information those you wanted to be exported[image]
- Click on finish button to complete export.

**Import Server List**

- Same way you just need to click **Import** instead of export and browse your exported JSON file
- Once you locate exported JSON file and follow the next instruction and finally click on the **Finish** button, server information will be imported.

Comment: It works, however passwords seem to be empty (not exported/imported), is it correct?

Comment: Yes, password is empty. I think it seems okay in terms of security.

Comment: This works with recent version of pgAdmin 4 (as export/import menu was added by pgAdmin development team), but it is not applicable to pgadmin version 4.2 which was refered by OP.